# confused about variables in bash

Tags: bash

I know that variables in bash have no type, but am confused about the value they are assigned.

The following simple script works fine in bash

```
#!/bin/bash 
tail -n +2 /cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)/workfile.txt > \
/cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)/workfile2.txt
```

However, the following does not

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpdir=/cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)
tail -n +2 $tmpdir/workfile.txt > $tmpdir/workfile2.txt
```

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure to quote variables that may have spaces in them. In your case, `tail` is receiving three files: `/cygdrive/c/workdir`, `(newco,` and `LLC)` because `$tmpdir` has three words separated by spaces.

I know you escaped the space when assigning `$tmpdir`, but that merely served to avoid each word being interpreted as a separate command during assignment. If you then `echo $tmpdir`, you will get
`/cygdrive/c/workdir (newco, LLC)`, and *that's* what's being passed to `tail`.

To avoid this, quote `$tmpdir`:

```
tail -n +2 "${tmpdir}/workfile.txt" > "${tmpdir}/workfile2.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between "${tmpdir}/workfile.txt" and "$tmpdir/workfile.txt"?

Comment: Curly braces are used to ensure proper parsing of variable names. If you had a variable called `tmp` you could do something like `${tmp}dir/workfile.txt` to substitute it instead of entire `$tmpdir` (assuming that one exists too).

Answer (score 0):

Type the first line in bash and then echo that variable, this is what you'll see:

```
$ tmpdir=/cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)
$ echo $tmpdir
/cygdrive/c/workdir (newco, LLC)
```

If it's not clear yet what's the culprit, add `echo` at the beginning of your second line and wrap it in double quotes. You'll see what command is actually executed:

```
$ echo "tail -n +2 $tmpdir/workfile.txt > $tmpdir/workfile2.txt"
tail -n +2 /cygdrive/c/workdir (newco, LLC)/workfile.txt > /cygdrive/c/workdir (newco, LLC)/workfile2.txt
```

You have properly escaped variable assignment, but that's not enough. Bash performs simple substring substitution, thus inserting additional spaces and breaking your command.

As @savanto suggested in his answer, you can wrap variables in double quotes to ensure that extra spaces aren't treated as argument separators. This line:

```
tail -n +2 "${tmpdir}/workfile.txt" > "${tmpdir}/workfile2.txt"
```

will look like this after variable substitution:

```
tail -n +2 "/cygdrive/c/workdir (newco, LLC)/workfile.txt" > "/cygdrive/c/workdir (newco, LLC)/workfile2.txt"
```

This is the most common and preferred way of solving that issue. If you desperately want to avoid double quotes, you can try double escaping: first when assigning, then after substitution.

```
$ tmpdir=/cygdrive/c/workdir\\\ \\\(newco\\\,\\\ LLC\\\)
$ echo $tmpdir
/cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)
```

Quick explaination of triple backslashes: a backslash means: "treat next character as a regular character, ignore any special meaning" (i.e. *escape it*). First backslash is an escape character, so second one will be treated as a backslash character, not escape character. Thus, double backslash produces a single backslash. Third one simply escapes following character, like space or parenthesis. For example `a\\\ b` will become `a\ b`.

Now if we substitute variables in your command, it will be escaped properly:

```
tail -n +2 /cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)/workfile.txt > /cygdrive/c/workdir\ \(newco\,\ LLC\)/workfile2.txt
```